# Why I can't toggle the switch button in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, checkbox, togglebutton

I have a switch to toggle in order to activate/ deactivate an account. In source code it looks like this:

`<input type="checkbox" name="acc-status" class="status-btn-checkbox" id="active-status">`

I need a code that will check if the account is active and will toggle the switch to 'active' if it's inactive.
I wrote something like this but it doesn't work:

```
//Check if Account is ACTIVE and activate if it's not
            
        String accactive = null;
        

        WebElement XActive = driver.findElement(By.id("active-status"));
        Boolean ActiveSwitch = XActive.isSelected();
        
        if(ActiveSwitch != true)
        {
            driver.findElement(By.id("active-status")).click();
        }
```

Comment: 1) Please add the switch element source both in active and inactive statuses. 2) Are you getting any exceptions with this code? If yes for what code line? 3) Try adding wait / delay before `WebElement XActive = driver.findElement(By.id("active-status"));` line

Comment: Is the checkbox even enabled? Can it be selected manualy? Btw you can write the code as `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("active-status"));
if (!element.isSelected()) {
 element.click();
}`